# My if-statements don't work

Tags: c, if-statement

There's a guy who wants to gamble on machines. He is a bit dumb though, so he wants to lose money, and won't play on a machine unless it'll make him lose money in the long run. There are three variables, N(a value between 1 and 100) - the amount of money he wins if he win, K(a value between 1 and 100) - the amount of money it costs to play and p(a float value between 0 and 1) - the probability of winning. This is the code I'm using:

```
int n;
int k;
float p;
cin >> n >> k >> p;
if( k-n > 0 )
{
    cout << "Play";
}
if( k-n == 0 )
{
    if( p == 1 )
    {
        cout << "Don't Play!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Play";
    }
}
if( k-n < 0 )
{
    if( p >= ((float)k/n) )
    {
        cout << "Don't Play!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Play";
    }
}
```

The code begins with adding the values to the variables. Then it checks if k is larger than n. If it is, then of course he is supposed to play. If it costs more than he can win, he'll always lose on the machine.

After that it checks if k = n. If it does, then he should only play if there's not a 100% win ratio, cause then he'll eventually lose money, otherwise he'll just stay on the same amount of money all the time.

Finally, it checks whether k is less than n or not, and this is where I think the problem is. If n is larger, then it depends on the value of p. If p is larger than k/n then one should not play. Example: k = 3 and n = 4. 3/4 = 0.75. If p = 0.75 then theoretically, the guy will win three times out of four. The times he'll win, he'll spend 9 and win 12, meaning he has 3 left. Then he'll lose one and get back to 0. Thus, if p >= k/n one shouldn't play because theoretically, you won't lose any money. But otherwise, if it's under k/n, it's good to go, you'll lose money.

When I compile this code on the website, it checks on 8 secret test values. This code finishes the first four but fails on the fifth. Something must be wrong. I can't, however, find out what it is.

Comment: Think about "if p == 1".   Can you really compare floats for equality?

Comment: Since this is a competition, don't you think you should try harder and win without external help?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo This is from a website for a competition. The problem itself is just a practice problem.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Well, I dunno, it seems like I can. If I put k = 5, n = 5 and p = 1 then I get the message Don't Play, and if I put k = 5, n = 5 and p = 0.999999 I get the message Play.

Comment: Do you think the logic about k==n is correct?  In your problem description you said he won't play on a machine that will make him win.   If k==n, he will never win anything, so he can play?

Comment: @GreenAsJade Sorry, that's a flaw in my description. What I meant is that he won't play on a machine unless he loses on it.

Comment: I guess you're sure that this is what the people who set the test think? ;)

Comment: @GreenAsJade This is what the problem says, roughly translated: Because Name is stupid, he thought one was supposed to lose as much money as possible. Thus, he only wants to play if the expected prize money is negative, that is, if he loses money in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You should read something about probability.

p >= ((float)k/n)

should be written as

p * (n - k) + (1 - p) * (0 - k) > 0

EDIT:

I am sorry, I made a mistake. I think it's a little more clean, and you don't get div by 0. But in fact they should be same.

Maybe you should make p double, and then you don't get wrong because of rounding problem.

Comment: I tried that out, and now the code only worked for 2/8 tests on the website. Why do you think it should be written as that instead?

Comment: And that's more easily written as pn - k > 0 anyway. So for it to be equal to what I wrote, it should just be pn - k >= 0.

Comment: I don't understand. If they are equal, why it fails more? Maybe you should consider the condition when n == 0 (and if rounding will affect the result)

Comment: n can't be 0, that's stated in the problem. And the thing you wrote is not the same thing I wrote, because mine is >= and yours is just > . I tried writing p*n - k >= 0 and got the same amounts of right answers as with my own code, so rounding doesn't seem to be the problem.